# block with out title space in a specific position and certain length (Title box in a poster)

Tags: beamer, beamerposter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Block with out title space in a specific position and certain length (for Title box in a poster)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54275/block-with-out-title-space-in-a-specific-position-and-certain-length-for-title)

I am preparing a poster with `beamer`. In title box, there is a blue banner space. How can I remove it? I write the title in such a way:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{textblock}{}[0,0.1](1cm,1cm)%
\begin{varblock}[75cm]{}
\vspace{-0.65cm}
\begin{center}
{
\Large {\textbf{\textcolor{violet!90}{Anticipated Complexities of Landfill to Estimate Fugitive $\mathrm{CH_{4}}$  using Micro-Meteorological Method.}}}\\
\vspace{0.5cm}
\normalsize {\textbf{ T$^1$, T$^1$, J$^1$, R$^2$}}\\ 
\vspace{0.5cm}
\textcolor {black}  {1.University of Alberta ~ 2.Research Branch, Agriculture and Agri-Food Canada}
\vspace{-0.5cm}
}
\end{center}
\end{varblock}
\end{textblock}
```

Also I have declare `varblock` to set the position in specific position inside the textblock.

```
\newenvironment<>{varblock}[2][\textwidth]{%
  \setlength{\textwidth}{#1}
  \begin{actionenv}#3%
    \def\insertblocktitle{#2}%
    \par%
    \usebeamertemplate{block begin}}
  {\par%
    \usebeamertemplate{block end}%
  \end{actionenv}}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please turn your code snippets into a *complete*, minimal document?

Comment: @Medina, below I write the code. I will appreciate your help.

Comment: @Mahzabin Please, edit your question and delete the previous comment.