# Block with out title space in a specific position and certain length (for Title box in a poster)

Tags: beamer, titles, beamerposter

I am working on a poster. As I need to draw a block in a specific position, I do that using `varblock`. All of this causes a banner at the top of my title block (see the picture). Is that possible to remove that only for my title box?

Here I include some of my code.

```
\documentclass[final, 12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[size=custom,width=77,height=107,scale=1.4,orientation=portrait]{beamerposter} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig,xcolor}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,tabularx,amsthm,multirow,amsmath}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newenvironment<>{varblock}[2][\textwidth]{
  \setlength{\textwidth}{#1}
  \begin{actionenv}#3
    \def\insertblocktitle{#2}
    \par
    \usebeamertemplate{block begin}}
  {\par
    \usebeamertemplate{block end}
  \end{actionenv}}
\usecolortheme{rose}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{textblock}{}[0,0.1](1cm,1cm)
\begin{varblock}[75cm]{}
\vspace{-0.65cm}
\begin{center}
{\Large {\textbf{\textcolor{violet!90}{Anticipated Complexities of Landfill to Estimate Fugitive $\mathrm{CH_{4}}$  using Micro-Meteorological Method.}}}\\
\vspace{0.5cm}
\normalsize {\textbf{ M$^1$, T$^1$, J$^1$, R$^2$}}\\ 
\textcolor {black}  {1.Uof A 2.Agri-Food Canada}}
\end{center}
\end{varblock}
\end{textblock}


\begin{textblock}{50cm}[0,-0.58](1cm,0cm)
\begin{varblock}[35cm]{\textbf{1. Introduction}}

blah blah 


\end{varblock}
\end{textblock}


\begin{textblock}{}[0,-1.4](1cm,0cm)%
\begin{varblock}[31cm]{\textbf{3. Site \& Equipment}}
blah blah 
\end{varblock}
\end{textblock}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Your code, as posted, doesn't compile (let alone generate the image you've posted). After I remove the (unnecessary) `pdftex` option from the `graphicx` package, I still get an error message, "Missing number, treated as zero." related to `l. 55 \end{frame}`. Please check your code and repost it, if necessary.

Comment: Ya, I also get that error message, I just skip it by pressing "enter button". Actually I have no idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were using the arguments of `textblock` in the wrong way (please refer to the `textpos` package documentation for details). Anyway, your problem is that, according to your definition of `varblock`, this new block expects a title; for the title of your poster, obviously you don't need this field, so instead of using `varblock` you can simply use a `beamercolorbox` with the appropriate color (in this case, the color `block body` used to typeset the body of ordinary blocks). The code below illustrate this idea; of course, feel free to make the necessary adjustments according to your needs (I wasn't sure about the exact desired position for the blocks):

```
\documentclass[final, 12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[size=custom,width=77,height=107,scale=1.4,orientation=portrait]{beamerposter} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig,xcolor}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,tabularx,amsthm,multirow,amsmath}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usecolortheme{rose}

\newenvironment<>{varblock}[2][\textwidth]{
  \setlength{\textwidth}{#1}
  \begin{actionenv}#3
    \def\insertblocktitle{#2}
    \par
    \usebeamertemplate{block begin}}
  {\par
    \usebeamertemplate{block end}
  \end{actionenv}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{textblock}{}(0.2,1)
\setlength{\textwidth}{75cm}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}{block body}
\vspace{-0.65cm}
\begin{center}
{\Large\textbf{\textcolor{violet!90}{Anticipated Complexities of Landfill to Estimate Fugitive $\mathrm{CH_{4}}$  using Micro-Meteorological Method.}}\\
\vspace{0.5cm}
\normalsize {\textbf{ M$^1$, T$^1$, J$^1$, R$^2$}}\\ 
\textcolor {black}  {1.Uof A 2.Agri-Food Canada}}
\end{center}
\end{beamercolorbox}
\end{textblock}

\begin{textblock}{}(0.28,2.2)
\begin{varblock}[35cm]{\textbf{1. Introduction}}
blah blah 
\end{varblock}
\end{textblock}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]